# Passing Parameters to Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to implement the contract below in REMIX.

If I try to pass parameters to appendTags as "`tag1`", I get an error as Error:

> invalid bytes32 value (arg="", type="string", value="tag1")

How can I pass parameters to the function appendTags in REMIX ?

```
contract Post{

struct tags{
bytes32[] tagged; 
}

mapping(address => tags) adminTags;

function appendTags(address addrs, bytes32 tag) public { 
 adminTags[addrs].tagged.push(tag); 
} 

function getTagsofAdmin(address addrs) public view returns(bytes32[]){ 
return adminTags[addrs].tagged; 
}

}
```

Comment: “Tag” is a string.

Comment: I did not understand well your problem. Use string as type for the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Solidity code specifies, you need to pass a `bytes32` value as argument, not an `ascii`-encoded word. This is an hexadecimal-encoded value, so as a rule of thumb it should start with `0x`.

Before passing your argument, you thus need to hex-encode it using for example one of web3 util's functions:

```
> web3.utils.fromAscii('tag1')
'0x74616731'
```

You can pass this hexadecimal value as an argument in the Remix console. Later when you call `getTagsOfAdmin` you'll simply need to apply the reverse transformation:

```
> web3.utils.toAscii('0x74616731')
'tag1'
```

Despite this added complexity, `bytes32` prove a good alternative against `strings` because they have fixed length and hence require way less storage costs. Hope it helps!

PS: note that the above command-line examples use web3 v1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @thomas-vanderstraeten